# Qooxdoo: Drag a toolbar button to a tree node. is it possible?

Tags: button, toolbar, drag, qooxdoo

I am trying to Drag a toolbar button to a tree node. Is it possible? I have noticed that drag start is never fired. Is there any list of components/classes available that currently allow to be dragged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toolbar buttons can not be dragged. Currently this feature is disabled in Qooxdoo. Instead You can use Menu Button. I know this is not proper way and not Elegant but at-least you can have the functionality you want.

And Sorry for the second Question about List of Drag-ables, There is no such list available yet

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It was really helpful. Now i am using Menu button with button decorator which gives almost what i wanted

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to Drag a toolbar button to a tree node. Is it possible?

Buttons can not be dragged, is is not a normal UI behavior. If you really want do drag a button, you have to implement your own behavior. Extend from the button and override the methods for mouse up and mouse down behavior.

> Is there any list of components/classes available that currently allow to be dragged?

Sorry, no, there is no list.